# turn the first letter into capital form using udf and map(), met unexpected outcomes

Tags: python-3.x

I was doing an exercise from a web tutorial. The original list is ['dog', 'cat'], and the aim is to return ['Dog', 'Cat'], instead it prints "map object at 0x0049F410". Can't see what is wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

```
def cap_upper(str):
    return [s.join (chr(ord(str[:1]) - 32) + (str[1:])) for s in str if ord(str[:1]) > 96]
L = ['dog', 'cat']
print (map(cap_upper, L))
```

update screenshot:

[image]

Comment: [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator, not a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `str` is a Python built-in name which you're overriding (it's used to get string representations of objects). That's bad practice, try not to do that. It could give you unexpected results.

For this case, Python has a built-in `upper` method, which is for exactly this purpose. No need to mess with character values when you don't have to.

Try this:

```
def cap_upper(s):
    return s[0].upper()+s[1:]
```

You also have to convert the `map` object to a `list` under Python 3 like:

```
list(map(my_list, my_function))
```

Now your example works perfectly:

```
>>> L = ['dog', 'cat']
>>> print(list(map(cap_upper, L)))
['Dog', 'Cat']
```

Comment: I typed according to what you give, strangely it still shows "<map object at 0x0058F410>". Am I missing something?

Comment: What is your *exact* input to the program? I suspect it's not `['dog', 'cat']` and your error lies somewhere else

Comment: I upload a screenshot in the question (typing in Sublime2). Have no idea about the outcome...

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
def cap_upper(str):
    if not str:
        return str
    first = str[0].upper()
    return first + str[1:]
```

Comment: it gives me 'File "C:\……\jointest2.py", line 5
    return str
             ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation'. I checked but there is no space mistake. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well I'm sure you have some tabs and some spaces in your source file.  Try reindenting what you copy-pasted.